# ActiveRecord Query to find JSON Value Array for a given Key

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

In Rails 4 I have a table with a JSON type column.  I have a method that works well like so

```
def self.that_match_property(key: "default", value: "default")
  where("properties ->> ? = ?", key, value)
end
```

So for `Model.first.properties` I get `{"name": "Bill", "user_id": "1"}`
I can do this just fine.

```
Model.that_match_property(key: "name", value: "Bill")
```

And I get the record or records that match on the key/value pair in my json `properties` column.

But... let's say I want the value to be an array of ids.  So I have...

```
user1.properties = {"name": "Bill", "user_id": "1"}
user2.properties = {"name": "Ted", "user_id": "2"}
user3.properties = {"name": "Rufus", "user_id": "3"}
```

Now I also have `bill_and_ted_ids = ["1", "2"]`

I want to be able to do this:

```
Model.that_match_property(key: "user_id", value: bill_and_ted_ids)
```

But this doesn't work.  Normally I could pass in an array of IDs to an active record query and it converts to the proper sql.

What is the correct way to do the above with a JSON data type in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will be helpfull:

```
def build_where_query_string_from_hash(hash)
  hash.collect do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Array)
      string = v.collect{|e| "(properties ->> '#{k}'='#{e}')"}.join(" OR ")
      "(#{string})"
    else
      "(properties ->> #'{k}'='#{v}')"
    end
  end.join(" AND ")
end
```

then you can pass: `build_where_query_string_from_hash(user_id: [1,2], name: ["Bill", "Ted"])`

which returns:

```
((properties ->> 'user_id'='1') OR (properties ->> 'user_id'='2')) AND ((properties ->> 'name'='Bill') OR (properties ->> 'name'='Ted'))`
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I'm trying to avoid using 2 ruby loops.  I already have it working where I can loop through the IDs and call the method with each id.  I'm looking to improve and use ARs lazy evaluation to make it more efficient.